# How to Document Custom Properties in axiosrequestconfig using jsdoc

Tags: axios, jsdoc, jsdoc3

I am using axios interceptors to customize the requests I send from my application. I am not using typescript and so I am documenting my code using JsDoc to help my futureself understand what some custom properties mean.

I have an axios Interceptor checking for a custom property added on the config object to help add Authorization header without much hassle:

```js
const http = axios.create({});
http.interceptors.request.use(
  async (config) => {
    if (config?.includeAuthorization) {
      config.withCredentials = true;
      const Cookies = require("js-cookie"); // Using require since dynamic import(above) fails to import module
        const token = Cookies.get(JWTAuthTokenName);

        if (token) {
          config.headers["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${token}`;
        }

      delete config.includeAuthorization;
    }

    return config;
  },
  function (error) {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);
```

I have a custom property `includeAuthorization` added to request config. This is not part of axios request config but Nonetheless, I would like to document with JsDoc telling its type and an explanation of what it does. I do not know how to go about this.

I have tried the following at the top of my file(*same file I've created Axios instance*):

```js
/**
 * @typedef {import("axios").AxiosRequestConfig} axios
 * @property {boolean} includeAuthorization - If `true`, Authorization header with value read from cookie is added to request
 *
 */
```

But this requires me to use the type definition I have created(`axios`). If I have to use it, then I do not know where. I expected this to extend AxiosRequestConfig globally and include my custom propery(`includeAuthorization`). That did not happen.
I would highly appreciate your input on how I can get around this problem.